# MySQL max_allowed_packet greater than 1024 MB

Tags: mysql

I have a DB which is greater than 1GB (~1,4GB). The DB upload was stopped at 1GB, because, max_allowed_packet is 1073741824 (1GB). In file /etc/my.conf i set max_allowed_packet=2048M.

How can I increase max_allowed_packet 1073741824 to bigger?

Thank You!

Comment: Please clarify what did you mean by 'DB upload'

Comment: Hello, how and where you uploading the db and what os you are using?

Answer (score 7):

### Bad News

The maximum value for [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is 1G or 1024M.

Even if you set it higher, MySQL will not load data beyond the 1GB limit.

### Good News

The MySQL Packet is for processing rows, especially in bulk. The smaller the TEXT/BLOB fields you have in your tables, the more robust the MySQL Packet will be used. So that you can be more confident in its usage, here is an explanation of just what a MySQL Packet is:

According to the [*page 99 of "Understanding MySQL Internals" (ISBN 0-596-00957-7)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
> written under the assumption that
> queries are always reasonably short,
> and therefore can be sent to and
> processed by the server in one chunk,
> which is called a *packet* in MySQL
> terminology. The server allocates the
> memory for a temporary buffer to store
> the packet, and it requests enough to
> fit it entirely. This architecture
> requires a precaution to avoid having
> the server run out of memory---a cap
> on the size of the packet, which this
> option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
> this option is found in
> **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
> particular attention to
> **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
> of a result of many string functons.
> See **sql/field.cc** and
> **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Comment: "The MySQL Packet is for processing rows". Not only unfortunely: it's also used by replication with binary logs... and it can cause Error 1236 "log event entry exceeded max_allowed_packet".